# AWS API Gateway - AWS Service Integration - Execution Role Inheritance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, api-gateway

Is it possible for the `Execution role` in the API Gateway AWS Service integration config to inherit policy permissions from the running user.

Currently we are using a custom authorizer for API auth which as its output returns a policy document with `statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'`. Is it possible to restrict or increase the permissions a API has when integrating API Gateway with other AWS services such as S3.

For example is it possible to have a custom authorizer with an API Gateway S3 proxy and set conditional IAM policy to only allow the userId (set via the `principalId`) to get S3 objects that are prefixed with their userId???

See execution role in this image from the AWS docs taken from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket);[image: AWS API Gateway Integration setup]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to pass through the IAM identity from the invoking user. You can do this by filling in `arn:aws:iam::*:user/*` as execution role.

More details can be found in the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-credentials)